# Is this a compact (closed + bounded) set of vectors in $\mathbb R^n$?

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, general-topology, compactness

If I take a set of normalized eigenvectors $h_n$ (in $\mathbb R^n$) that correspond to the largest eigenvalues of matrices $A_n$, is this set of eigenvectors compact - i.e., closed and bounded?

The set is obviously bounded, but I'm not sure whether the set is closed - I am probably just overlooking something trivial.

Do I just consider a convergent sequence in this set and since the limit vector will again be in the set (normalized, corresponds to the largest eigenvalue of some matrix $A_n$) then by definition this set is closed?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The set is finite (it has no more than $n$ linearly independent vectors), so it's trivially compact.

If you would like to see this with a sequence, take any infinite sequence $\{x_n\}_n$in that set. As the set is finite, at least one of the elements of the set must be infinitely repeated in the sequence, let's call it $y$. Then, the constant subsequence $\{y\}_k=\{x_{n_k}\}_k$ is obviously convergent, then the set is compact.

Note: I never used that we're working in $\Bbb R^n$, in fact, this proof works for any finite subset of a normed space.

Comment: Ah, that's pretty cool - thanks so much, @GLay :)

Comment: @Lin I added a note at the end.

Comment: Ah, got it - thanks for the extra detail, @GLay :)

Comment: @Lin Also, be careful when saying compact=closed+bounded. That is only truth for finite dimensional vector spaces.

Comment: Thanks again for the additional, helpful comment, @Glay :)